# Creating table and layer using ArcObjects in c#

Tags: arcobjects, table

I have used Make XY Event Layer to Creates a new point feature layer based on x- and y-coordinates using python and it worked for me. Now as a need of my project i want to apply the same in c# using ARCObject SDK10.0 . Additionally, i also want to create a table in geodatabase to hold all the xy points in the table with following field : ObjectID, Xcoor,ycoor, Shape.

How do I do this in c#?

Answer (score 4):

Based on [pecoanddeco's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61285), here is the VBA code converted to C#.

Note that you'll need to create the `XYSample.txt` file and add it to your map as described [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000010r000000)

Need to add the following ArcGIS References

- ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI
- ESRI.ArcGIS.CartoESRI
- ESRI.ArcGIS.CartoUI
- ESRI.ArcGIS.Display
- ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework
- ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase
- ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry
- ESRI.ArcGIS.LoctationUI

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework; 
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.LocationUI;

    void AddXYEventLayer()
    {
        IMxDocument mxdoc = ArcMap.Application.Document as IMxDocument;
        IMap map = mxdoc.FocusMap;

        // Get the table named XYSample.txt
        IStandaloneTableCollection stTableCollection = map as IStandaloneTableCollection;
        IStandaloneTable standaloneTable = null;
        ITable table = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < stTableCollection.StandaloneTableCount; i++)
        {
            standaloneTable = stTableCollection.StandaloneTable[i];
            if (standaloneTable.Name == "XYSample.txt")
            {
                table = standaloneTable.Table;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (table == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("XYSample.txt table was not found in this map.");
            return;
        }

        // Get the table name object
        IDataset dataset = table as IDataset;
        IName tableName = dataset.FullName;

        // Specify the X and Y fields
        IXYEvent2FieldsProperties xyEvent2FieldsProperties = new XYEvent2FieldsProperties() as IXYEvent2FieldsProperties;
        xyEvent2FieldsProperties.XFieldName = "x";
        xyEvent2FieldsProperties.YFieldName = "y";
        xyEvent2FieldsProperties.ZFieldName = "";

        // Specify the projection
        ISpatialReferenceFactory spatialReferenceFactory = new SpatialReferenceEnvironment() as ISpatialReferenceFactory;
        IProjectedCoordinateSystem projectedCoordinateSystem = spatialReferenceFactory.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_NAD1983UTM_11N);

        // Create the XY name object as set it's properties
        IXYEventSourceName xyEventSourceName = new XYEventSourceName() as IXYEventSourceName;
        xyEventSourceName.EventProperties = xyEvent2FieldsProperties;
        xyEventSourceName.SpatialReference = projectedCoordinateSystem;
        xyEventSourceName.EventTableName = tableName;

        IName xyName = xyEventSourceName as IName;
        IXYEventSource xyEventSource = xyName.Open() as IXYEventSource;

        // Create a new Map Layer
        IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer() as IFeatureLayer;
        featureLayer.FeatureClass = xyEventSource as IFeatureClass;
        featureLayer.Name = "Sample XY Event Layer";

        // Add the layer extension (this is done so that when you edit
        // the layer's Source properties and click the Set Data Source
        // button, the Add XY Events Dialog appears)
        ILayerExtensions layerExtensions = featureLayer as ILayerExtensions;
        XYDataSourcePageExtension resPageExtension = new XYDataSourcePageExtension();
        layerExtensions.AddExtension(resPageExtension);

        map.AddLayer(featureLayer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example for ArcObjects 9.

[Create a layer based on XY data](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/samples/tables/create_a_layer_based_on_xy_data.htm)

There's also one for ArcObjects 10, but it's only got the VBA code and not the .net code, though hopefully not much has changed so the v9 code should still work.

[How to create a layer based on XY data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000010r000000)